# Missing items in Notepad++ Menu

Tags: notepad++

This might be a bit off-topic question but I could not get help from anywhere else.

Earlier Notepad++ had **Stream Comment** and **Toggle Block Comment** option in the menu, but now I cannot find it. Is there anyway to add these options in the menu? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad 6.3.2 they are in the menus, see **Edit** => **Comment/uncomment**. They are not available in the right-mouse context menu on my computer.

The context menu can be edited so you should be able add other commands as described in the support documentation, see http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Context_Menu

Comment: Please note that if you open your `contextMenu.xml` you will find the `Toggle block comment` and `Stream comment` options already available. But they not working. The reason seems to be because in the latest versions of N++ the commands have been renamed. All you have to do is rename them exactly as they appear in the Edit menu.

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

In this directory rename **contextmenu.xml** to **contextmenu2.xml** 
or delete it .

Then run notepad++ again. You will see new contextmenu.